# Bad Request: message to edit not found error (python telebot)

Tags: python, error-handling, telebot

Inline buttons of my telegram bot '+' and '-' after a certain time stop responding - they work, they change the variable quantity of goods, but when you click on one of them does not change the product message with the selected product. This causes the error I wrote

Good afternoon everyone. I am making a telegram bot on python (telebot). The essence of the following block of code is as follows: the user has selected a product, which is stored in the variable `choice`, then the previous message with the choice of the product is edited to the instruction: 'To edit the amount of the product, use buttons + and -', and this message is accompanied by buttons '+', '-' and 'Confirm quantity'.

```
global amount, last_message_id, total
        if callback.data=='+':
            amount+=0.25
            price_per_gram_ = products[choice]['price_per_gram']    #link to the price for the selected item in the dictionary
            max_ = products[choice]['max']                          #max. threshold for the selected quantity of an item in the dictionary
            min_ = products[choice]['min']                          #min threshold
            total = amount*price_per_gram_
            kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='+', callback_data='+')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='-', callback_data='-') 
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Назад в меню товаров', callback_data='back2')
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅ Confirm amount', callback_data='confirm_amount')
            kb.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)
            if amount <= max_ and amount >= min_:
                global text
                text='⭐ Product: ' + choice + ' \n Selected quantity: ' + str(amount) + ' kg' + ' \n Price: ' + str(total)
            else:
                text='❗❗ The quantity of the products may not exceed ' + str(max_) + ' kg' +' and it can't be less ' + str(min_) + ' kg!'
            if last_message_id:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,message_id=last_message_id,text=text, reply_markup=kb)  
            else:
                sent_message=bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,message_id=callback.message.id, text=text, reply_markup=kb)
                last_message_id=sent_message.message_id
 
        if callback.data=='-':
            if amount >= 0.25:
                amount-=0.25
                kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='+', callback_data='+')
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='-', callback_data='-') 
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=' Back to the catalog of goods', callback_data='back2')
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='✅ Confirm amount', callback_data='confirm_amount')
                kb.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)  
                price_per_gram_ = products[choice]['price_per_gram']    #link to the price for the selected item in the dictionary
                max_ = products[choice]['max']                          #max. threshold for the selected quantity of an item in the dictionary
                min_ = products[choice]['min']                          #min threshold
                total = amount*price_per_gram_
                text='⭐ Product: ' + choice + ' \n� Selected quantity: '+ str(amount) + ' kg' + ' \n Price: ' + str(total)
                if last_message_id:
                    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,message_id=last_message_id,text=text, reply_markup=kb)
                else:
                    sent_message=bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,message_id=callback.message.id, text=text, reply_markup=kb)
                    last_message_id=sent_message.message_id
            else:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id, text='❗❗ The quantity of goods cannot be negative!')
```

- **What does the bot do?**
  The '+' button increases the item amount by 0.25 and when pressed, the instruction message is edited to the order message, only with the changed item amount (similarly, the '-' button decreases the amount). By default the `amount=1`. This order message after pressing the + or - button has an id `last_message_id` (if there was `callback.message.id`, the bot would change the original order message, not the one that was already changed after selecting the item amount)

(Item: banana

Selected quantity: 1,25

Price: 175)

After selecting the item quantity, you can confirm it, after which the bot displays a residual order message, after which the purchase procedure is complete.

- **What is the problem?**
  The problem itself is that after several purchases in the bot, the + and - buttons stop responding. The order message is not shown at all. That is, after selecting a product there is an instruction 'Use the + and - buttons to change the quantity of the product', the buttons are added, but nothing happens when you click on them. Nevertheless, if you click on 'Confirm quantity', the bot displays a residual order message with the changed quantity of the product. That is, the + and - buttons worked, but the message was not edited after clicking on them, but only after clicking on 'Confirm quantity'.
  At the same time, a traceback pops up in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 1082, in __threaded_polling 
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions() 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions 
    raise self.exception_info 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 90, in run 
    task(*args, **kwargs) 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 6793, in _run_middlewares_and_handler 
    result = handler'function' 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/bot/shoporder70.py", line 409, in bot_message 
    sent_message = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=last_message_id, text=text, reply_markup=kb) 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/init.py", line 3831, in edit_message_text 
    result = apihelper.edit_message_text(self.token, text, chat_id, message_id, inline_message_id, parse_mode, 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 1329, in edit_message_text 
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post') 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 164, in _make_request 
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result) 
  File "/home/ognemetnikhans/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 191, in _check_result 
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json) 
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to edit not found'
```

Why does this error occur and how to fix it?

- **My guess**

I think that it is the `last_message_id` variable, because it is the one that is set in the condition of editing the order message after clicking on '+' or '-', but there is nowhere else in the code and it is used only in this code block.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).